# Display coupon code in order grid

Tags: magento-1.7, collection, grid, coupon, order-grid

I want to display the coupon code used, if any, in the orders grid.
The field should be filterable and sortable.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The below answer will show Ambiguous status column error when you filter collection using  as "status" column is in both the tables, so to resolve this we have to add below line before           `$this->setCollection($collection);`

`$collection->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status);`

Answer (score 0):

Main class for order grid is "Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid", if you want to add some column you have to rewrite this class like below :

**config.xml**

```
<blocks>
    <adminhtml>
        <rewrite>
            <sales_order_grid>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
        </rewrite>
    </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

You need to join `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid` table in order to show `coupon_code` in sales order grid.

**Grid.php**

```
<?php
/**
* Sales Order Class
*/
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{  
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('order' =>     Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')),
        'order.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',array('coupon_code' => 'coupon_code'))
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('coupon_code', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Color Name'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'coupon_code',
              'filter_index' => 'order.coupon_code'
        ));


        parent::_prepareColumns();
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```